# ¿Como editar una imagen subida a la base de datos Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo un proyecto en el cual registro una serie de películas para que un usuario pueda alquilarlas o comprarlas , cada película contiene **Nombre , Autor , Genero , Descripción , Precio y Una Imagen**  al momento de registrar la películas , todo perfecto el problema esta al querer editarla Me Sale este error

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined variable: Nombre_Imagen

**Crear Pelicula**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->hasFile('Imagen_Pelicula')) {
            $archivo = $request->file('Imagen_Pelicula');
            $Nombre_Imagen = time().$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
            $archivo->move(public_path().'/img/peliculas' , $Nombre_Imagen );
        }


        $pelicula = New Pelicula();
        $pelicula->nombre_pelicula = $request->Nombre_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->autor_pelicula = $request->Autor_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->genero_pelicula = $request->Genero_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->descripcion_pelicula = $request->Descripcion_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->precio_pelicula = $request->Precio_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->imagen_pelicula = $Nombre_Imagen;
        $pelicula->save();
        return redirect('peliculas');

    }
```

**Editar Pelicula**

```
public function edit( Request $request , $id )
    {
        $pelicula = Pelicula::findOrFail($id);  
        return view('peliculas.edit' , compact('pelicula'));
    }
```

**Actualizar Pelicula**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('Imagen_Pelicula')) {
            $archivo = $request->file('Imagen_Pelicula');
            $Nombre_Imagen = time().$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
            $archivo->move(public_path().'/img/peliculas' , $Nombre_Imagen );   
        }


       $pelicula = Pelicula::findOrFail($id);

        $pelicula->nombre_pelicula = $request->Nombre_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->autor_pelicula = $request->Autor_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->genero_pelicula = $request->Genero_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->descripcion_pelicula = $request->Descripcion_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->precio_pelicula = $request->Precio_Pelicula;
        $pelicula->imagen_pelicula = $Nombre_Imagen;

        // return $request;
        $pelicula->save();
        return redirect('peliculas');
    }
```

**Formulario**

```
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('peliculas.index') }}"> Ver Peliculas  </a>
<form style="width: 400px;border:0px red solid;margin:auto"  method="post" action="{{ route('peliculas.update', $pelicula->id) }}" >
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Nombre_Pelicula">Nombre Pelicula</label>
       <input type="Nombre_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Nombre_Pelicula" id="Nombre_Pelicula" value="{{$pelicula->nombre_pelicula}}" >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Autor_Pelicula">Autor</label>
       <input type="Autor_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Autor_Pelicula" id="Autor_Pelicula" value="{{$pelicula->autor_pelicula}}">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Genero_Pelicula">Genero</label>
       <input type="Genero_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Genero_Pelicula" id="Genero_Pelicula" value="{{$pelicula->genero_pelicula}}">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12" >
      <label for="Descripcion_Pelicula">Descripcion</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="Descripcion_Pelicula" id="Descripcion_Pelicula" >{{$pelicula->descripcion_pelicula}} </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="Precio_Pelicula">Precio</label>
      <input type="Precio_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Precio_Pelicula" id="Precio_Pelicula" value="{{floatval($pelicula->precio_pelicula)}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="Imagen_Pelicula">Imagen Pelicula</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="Imagen_Pelicula" id="Imagen_Pelicula">
    </div>
   </div>
   {{csrf_field()}}
   @method('PUT')
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
 </form>
 <br>
```

Comment: Al `<form>` le falta `enctype="multipart/form-data"` que permite se envíen archivos por el formulario

Comment: Al actualizar tienes esta linea `$pelicula->imagen_pelicula = $Nombre_Imagen;` Parece ser que Nombre_Imagen no esta definida en ese ambito.

Comment: Solo para aclarar, no la actual respuesta! Esta variable Nombre_Imagen, solo estan en la lógica de [Crear Película] y [Actualizar Película], Por lo que segun tu logica la variable Nombre_Imagen, sólo será definida si existe el archivo en el request, usualmente solo existe cuando se envía, luego lo que se suele ver normalmente es una referencia al recurso en algún server, ejemplo: url.

Comment: entonces de que mera puedo resolver ese problema??